# Why "mvn site" is running tests?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-site-plugin

I have the following build configuration for a Spring Boot application.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>                
            <version>2.22.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run mvn site, I expect the site goal of the site phase to execute. But my tests are running, which means the test goal of the default lifecycle is also getting executed.

I know I can skip running the test with `-DskipTets`, but I want to understand why this is happening?